# Increase the value of count in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two tables rta_list and rta_reg_company. I have a column count in rta_list table.

```
 Schema::create('rta_list', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('rta_id');
    $table->string('rta_name');
    $table->string('rta_address');
    $table->string('rta_phone');
    $table->string('rta_email')->unique();
    $table->integer('count'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});

 Schema::create('rta_reg_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('company_id');
    $table->integer('rta_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('rta_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('rta_lists')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('company_name');
    $table->string('company_isin');
    $table->string('company_script');
    $table->string('company_address');
    $table->string('company_phone');
    $table->string('company_email');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to increase the value of count of rta_list table by rta_id when I add new RTA Registered Company. For eg: if i add one company then, The value must be added in rta_reg_company table and count must be 1 in count column in rta_list table.

Also also how to show the count value by rta_id in view..
Help Needed.....

Comment: Write a query which updates `count` field.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [laravel Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers) to raise an event on a model creation.then you can update as below on model Observer:

```
public function created(Company $company)
    {
        DB::table('rta_list')->increment('count');
    }
```